# Sikuli and Appium

Tags: selenium, appium, sikuli

Is it advisable to use Sikuli along with Appium ?

I tried finding an image after launching app on device using Appium, but sikuli returned an error saying "cannot find img/x.png on the screen".

Comment: Why you want to use sikuli with appium?

Comment: My main aim is verify 'GUI only' on different screen resolutions on real devices without much modification of scripts, have used Sikuli along with Selenium so thought about inheriting that with appium.

Comment: I see , Then You can also ask same question here : discuss.appium.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is possible to use Sikuli for mobile too. With Appium.
[Here is example](http://dzaiats.github.io/appium-sikuli-driver/) of how to do it. 
in this project is described the process how to setup and how to use this framework. Examples are attached.

Comment: One Liners are not very helpful in answering the queries of OP. Please add some description around the answer.